Anaconda InvalidArchiveError when following tutorial for VSCode Data Science
I'm trying to get a more practical grip on data science with Python and thought it would be a good idea to follow a tutorial (hoping to avoid doing lots of troubleshooting). However, I didn't get very far until the mess started.
I follow this tutorial https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/data-science-tutorial
As the tutorial suggests, I have installed miniconda, but when trying to create the environment and installing the required packages (step 1 - run the following in an Anacodna command prompt: conda create -n myenv python=3.10 pandas jupyter seaborn scikit-learn keras tensorflow ), I immidiately run in to trouble and get this error:
InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\miniconda3\pkgs\tensorflow-base-2)
Tried searching for this error, asked copilot for help, but nothing suggested seems to work and I cannot continue the tutorial without it...
Any ideas?
I tried updating Conda using
conda update conda

Tried cleaning up
conda clean --all

Verified that I have full control of the directory.
Ensured I have plenty of free space on the drive.

Did you try the suggestion here to clean out the associated package location? In your system, it looks like it would be found in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\miniconda3\pkgs.

Hi and thanks for the advice, couldn't find any Continuum folder but a miniconda3 folder directly in Local, there I removed all openssl **then installed from libarchive''then tried creating the environment again.
But still the same error
